# Is this exponential equation solvable? natural logarithms, exponential

Tags: exponential-function

$$\displaystyle{a=\frac{e^{-cos(\frac{b}{x})}-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x}})}}$$

I'm trying to solve for $x$. $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks 
Ghassan

Comment: No reasonable attack in sight. Look for a numerical method.

Comment: Solution would be obtained using numerical methods.

Comment: When you have lots of nested exponents and fractions, you can use the latex \large{} or \huge{} to make them more visible.  You probably noticed already but you can rewrite this as $\large{0 = e^{-\cos(b/x)} + (a - 1)e^{-1/x} - a}$ and apply newton's method for finding roots.

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle{a=\frac{e^{-cos(\frac{b}{x})}-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x}})}}$

We can make things a bit more manageable by letting $t = -\dfrac{1}{x}$ giving us

$\displaystyle{a=\frac{e^{-cos(bt)}-e^{t}}{(1-e^{t})}}$

which we can write as

$\displaystyle{cos(bt)=-\ln{(e^t + a(1-e^t))}}$

As you can see in [this animated graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vrgx7k3tvu) there is always at least one solution, and possibly infinitely many more, depending on the value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is no solution which can be expressed using elementary function and root finding methods should be used. For illustration purposes, I shall consider $$f(x)=\displaystyle{\pi+\frac{e^{-cos(\frac{e}{x})}-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x}})}}$$ and use Newton iterative scheme $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Starting far away from the solution (say, at $x_0=2$), the successive iterates are $4.35491$, $6.30492$,$6.41182$, $6.41195$ which is the solution for six significnt figures.